# FetchType.Lazy not working in JPA in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity Order.java as:

```
package in.ashwin.onlinebookstore.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_order")
public class Order {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long order_id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    
    @Column(name="today_date")
    private Date todayDate;
    
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;
    
    public Order(User user, Date todayDate) {
        
        this.user = user;
        this.todayDate = todayDate;
        this.status="pending";
    }

    public Long getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(Long order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Date getTodayDate() {
        return todayDate;
    }

    public void setTodayDate(Date todayDate) {
        this.todayDate = todayDate;
    }
    
    public Order() {
        
    }

}
```

I have included Fetchtype as lazy between User and Order.Since,I have declared FetchType.LAZY while fetching Order then,I am still seeing user object called when I tested from postman.According to my understanfing,the object of FetchType.LAZY is only called when its needed.If,it is not called then ,it is ignored.

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        private User user;
```

My api to get all the Orders is:

```
@GetMapping("/getAllPendingOrders")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getOrders(Pageable pageable) {
        
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String user = auth.getName();
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails=(UserDetailsImpl)userdetailService.loadUserByUsername(user);
        
        Page<Order> orderList=orderRep.findByUserId(userDetails.getId(),pageable);
        if(orderList!=null) {
             return new ResponseEntity(orderList, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
             return new ResponseEntity("Noorders", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
       
        
    }
```

The Response I am getting back from POSTMAN is:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "ashwin",
                "email": "ashwin@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$GoGUJh0Tzml5egBW5Wzbj.VLzfq4Z7YNCMnsOynLWufpQrWBdVLVi",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "ROLE_MODERATOR"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ROLE_USER"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "todayDate": "2020-07-02T17:09:45.057+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "ashwin",
                "email": "ashwin@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$GoGUJh0Tzml5egBW5Wzbj.VLzfq4Z7YNCMnsOynLWufpQrWBdVLVi",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "ROLE_MODERATOR"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ROLE_USER"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "todayDate": "2020-07-02T17:15:06.906+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 3,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "ashwin",
                "email": "ashwin@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$GoGUJh0Tzml5egBW5Wzbj.VLzfq4Z7YNCMnsOynLWufpQrWBdVLVi",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "ROLE_MODERATOR"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ROLE_USER"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "todayDate": "2020-07-02T17:16:36.373+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 4,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "ashwin",
                "email": "ashwin@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$GoGUJh0Tzml5egBW5Wzbj.VLzfq4Z7YNCMnsOynLWufpQrWBdVLVi",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "ROLE_MODERATOR"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "ROLE_USER"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "todayDate": "2020-07-02T17:18:56.799+0000",
            "status": "pending"
        }
       
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true,
            "empty": true
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 20,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 2,
    "last": false,
    "totalElements": 39,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true,
        "empty": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 20,
    "first": true,
    "empty": false
}
```

I am still seeing the user object in my JSON.USing, `@JSONIgnore` works,but since I have declared it as `Fetchtype.Lazy` why the `USER` object is coming when I am fetching `Order` object?I dont want the User object to appear,when I am fetching the Order object.

Comment: The Fetchtype.Lazy just mean that whenever you call an order, the user is not going to come at the same time, just when it is needed, another query to the DB will be done to obtain this information. In this case, you have your repository and this is calling all the information on order, because it is needed to create the JSON.

Comment: So,this means that repository ignores FetchType.Laay?

Comment: As you are not marking the property as @JSONIgnore, it is calling the getter for all the properties inside order, it is not ignoring the Lazy, is using it when you call the getter.

Answer (score 0):

`User` entity data won't be initialized and loaded into memory until an explicit call is made to it. Your `Order` entity contains `user` field. So when serializing the order data getter of user called and user data fetched using another query.

If you don't want to use @JsonIgnore the create a response class for order without user field and map you data.

Comment: So,suppose if i remove the getter of user and still put the Fetchtype.lazy then how can i access suppose if i need order.getUser(). How can I access the user object ? Though there may be getters or not,if we declared Fetchtype.Lazy then it will omit user object yes?

Answer (score 0):

for me Adding **@JsonIgnore** annotation helped

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30654998)